# TextBox text as parameter n Double Click event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parameters, textbox

I have a form with 3 `TextBox`. All these controls contains some folder paths. I want to use same event as for all 3 textboxes. When I double click the texbox then I want to open the path of that textbox in an explorer. I set up the event as

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtSource" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding SelectSource}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="23" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxMouseDoubleClick}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"></MouseBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Now I want to pass the textbox text as parameter. So if I double click 1st textbox then the text of that textbox should be used as a parameter. And same scenario for some 2 controls. And I am not sure how to pass self control text here. Can anybode help me out here?

Now I have a solution of creating 3 different events for each textbox and I dont to do that.

**Edit with New Question**

I thought to edit this question instead of creating a new thread. I solved the above problem. Now when I double click the textbox, then the path is opened in a new window. But when I edit the path of the textbox then also the old path is opened. New path is not processed until I hit tab from the textbox or click on another control and then double click the textbox again. Can anybody help me with this? `XAML` for the textbox is given in above question.

Comment: hmmm....I did the same way. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid. I could have figured it out. That is how I did it.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtSource1" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding SelectSource1}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="23" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxMouseDoubleClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectSource1}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"></MouseBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>

<TextBox x:Name="TxtSource2" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding SelectSource2}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="23" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxMouseDoubleClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectSource2}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"></MouseBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>

<TextBox x:Name="TxtSource3" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding SelectSource3}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="23" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxMouseDoubleClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectSource3}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"></MouseBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

In short, I have binded text property for the textbox in ViewModel. I am simply passing the binded text property as parameter. Thanks all for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify `CommandParameter` this way:

```
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxMouseDoubleClick}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TxtSource, Path=Text}"
    MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"/>
```

Comment: +1...Thanks...I figured it out myself...but honestly what you answered was unknown to me. Learnt something new...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CommandParameter, for example:

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxMouseDoubleClick}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TxtSource, Path=Text}"
                  MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

Comment: +1...Thanks...I figured it out myself...but honestly what you answered was unknown to me. Learnt something new...:)